# how to print floats with 6 digits only - Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Okay..
I have these float numbers in a ruby array :-) 
12.321912389
122.438783
345.23242444
89.37827383

I want to convert these numbers to 6 digits numbers without losing float property. 
something like :-) 
12.3219
122.438
345.232
89.3782

Which function can help me? sorry if this question is very naive to you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can play with [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001432) "g" format, what you need is 6 *significant* digits:

```
(0..6).map{|i| '%.6g' % (10.0**i / 3)}
=> ["0.333333", "3.33333", "33.3333", "333.333", "3333.33", "33333.3", "333333"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very stupid (and slow), but it works (assuming numbers contain decimal point):

```
numbers = [12.321912389, 122.438783, 345.23242444, 89.37827383]
numbers.map! { |num| num.to_s[0..6].to_f }
p numbers    #=> [12.3219, 122.438, 345.232, 89.3782]
```